# Load UserDefault and loop them

Tags: swift, foreach, userdefaults

I have this Struct

```
struct DispItem: Identifiable, Codable {
let id = UUID()
let name: String
```

}

which I have in UserDefaults by this way:

```
init() {
    if let items = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "DispItems") {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        if let decoded = try? decoder.decode([DispItem].self, from: items) {
            self.items = decoded
            
            return
        }
    }
    
    self.items = []
}
```

Inside a "Dispense" class.

Inside another Swift View file I would like to load this UserDefaults "DispItems" and cycle the values.
I am still at the beginning of Swift/SwiftUI and the code I used to store it was taken from a couple of tutorial.
I assume that if I load it by doing so:

```
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(items) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "Items")
        }
```

But I assume that "items" will contain a Struct; how can I take the values and display them inside a ForEach loop?

Thanks
Marco

Answer (score 0):

I like to use `UserDefaults.standard.set(try? PropertyListEncoder().encode(items), forKey: "DispItems")`. This way you can encode, and then you can decode by using

```
typealias DispItems = [DispItem]

guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "player") as? Data else {
       return
   }
  guard let dispItems = try? PropertyListDecoder().decode(DispItems.self, from: data) else {
       return
   }

  dispItems.forEach{
   //Do what you'd like with the items
}
```